# Why does my TouchPhase.Began not work like this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, game-engine

I don't understand why `Input.GetTouch` is not working here.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 vel = rb.velocity;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y, x: 10) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 2000f);
    }
    if (Input.GetTouch(TouchPhase.Began))
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 2000f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea how to put that into my code for my case.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) expects an index .. you are passing in an enum value.

The [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.Moved.html) actually has a couple of examples how to use touch in Unity.

In your case you only want to check if there is a first touch in the state `Began` so you can use e.g.

```
private void Update () {
    Vector2 vel = rb.velocity;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2 (vel.y, x : 10) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) {
        rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 2000f);
    }

    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 2000f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh I understant.

Comment: @CooleSockeJr. please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) an answer if one answered your question.

Comment: Yes. I try it on my phone but it doesn't recognize my touches. @derHugo